# How to make 'rainbow' border movement on scroll

Tags: css, scroll, background-image, border, linear-gradients

I am trying to recreate an effect similar to the hover state on the https://codepen.io/ 'Start Coding' button on desktop (a rainbow border which moves), however to I want the movement to occur during scroll and then to stop when the user stops scrolling.

The codepen 'Start Coding' button is made of two components which give the impression of a rainbow border. A rainbow div and a black span within it. The span is smaller than the div, giving the impression of the rainbow border.

[image: Start Coding button with span transparent]

[image: Start Coding button with the span as black]

Comment: It would helpful if you can let us know what have you tried so far.

Comment: FYI Your link is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use javascript to do something only when scrolling. I can show you how with jquery. Maybe someone else can do it with vanilla js.

> You should add css animation frames to your element ([more info](http://tutorialspark.com/css3/CSS3_Animation_Keyframes.php)) and put them in a paused state `animation-play-state: paused;`. Then on scroll just set the `animation-play-state: running;` and if the user doesn't scroll for a brief period, then set it back to `animation-play-state: paused;` We can do so with jquery using [`.scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/),  like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //animation plays only when window scrolls
    //1 catch window scrolling
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        //2 change play state to running
        $( '.scrollcolors' ).css( 'animation-play-state', 'running' );
        //3 when window stops scrolling
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
            $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
                //4 set play state back to paused
                $( '.scrollcolors' ).css( 'animation-play-state', 'paused' );
            //5 set time without scrolling
            }, 500));
        });
    });

});
```

Working example (including html and css) here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af3tpcq1/12/)
*The jsfiddle uses the window for scrolling.*

And included here in this snippet *using a container for scrolling*:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //animation plays only when window scrolls
    //1 catch window scrolling
    $('.container').scroll(function() {
        //2 change play state to running
        $( '.scrollcolors' ).css( 'animation-play-state', 'running' );
        //3 when window stops scrolling
        $('.container').scroll(function() {
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
            $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
                //4 set play state to paused
                $( '.scrollcolors' ).css( 'animation-play-state', 'paused' );
            //5 set time without scrolling
            }, 500));
        });
    });
    
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
}
.scrollcolors span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.6em;
}
.sc1{
  top: 20px;
}
.sc2{
  top: 170px;
}
.sc3{
  top: 320px;
}
.scrollcolors {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #cf2525, #e0c71b 1rem, #0caa0d 2rem, #234ac1 3rem, #7e1cc2 4rem, #cf2525 5rem);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 1000%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  animation-name: colors;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 18.9% 18.9%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scrollcolors sc1">
    <span>scroll to animate</span>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollcolors sc2">
    <span>scroll to animate</span>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollcolors sc3">
    <span>scroll to animate</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

- I did not precisely duplicate codepen's gradient colors, I just did a quick general rainbow gradient.
- There is probably a better way to setup a seamlessly repeating animated gradient. I set the background size to 1000% and animated the position to move at the same 45 degree angle as the gradient to avoid any apparent seams.

Comment: Hey, thank you for this. It's a great solution. Do you have a slight delay on your machine? As in when you stop scrolling it seems to run for a moment longer and then stop the movement?

Comment: Yes. See the comment in the script where it say `//5 set time without scrolling` the line beneath has the number for the timeout function. That is the time that the user must not scroll before it registers. It is set in milliseconds. It is set at 500 so that is half a second. You can set it down to 200 or 100 and it will be nearly instant. I would not suggest setting it lower than 100.

Comment: Thank you. Why would you not go down lower than 100? In my head I'd put it down to 0... (Edit: I set to zero in the jsfiddle and it is the perfect effect that I want. Thank you for your help with it!)

Comment: because it will try to check a million times per second which will cause it to run poorly. Technically everything is digital on the computer. so scrolling send scroll stop scroll stop scroll, on and off. So it may rerun the whole function many times over, needlessly. Better to throttle functions which check window resizing scrolling, things which seem continuous. A 10th of a second (100 milliseconds) is fast enough response for something like this.

Comment: hmm ok, that's a good point. Can you think of a way to improve the performance with the same level of responsiveness as 0?

Comment: No, but you could try 50? If it is that important then use 20 maybe. Probably best not to use 0, but it depends on the page and what other scripts you may have running. If setting it very low, like 5, doesn't seem to cause any problems, then I guess it is okay. The difference between 5 and 0 must be imperceptible.

Comment: Thank you, 20 was a good idea and gives the same feel but probably doesn't smash the computer as much!